# Map doesn't exist on Observable<Object> with angular 6.0.0 and rxjs 6.1.0

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on Angular but the tutorial was made in September. I believe the person used `angular-cli 1.3.2`. I'm not sure which version of `rxjs` they were using. I'm using Angular CLI 6.0.0 and Angular 6 with `rxjs` 6.1.0.

I am running into a problem where calling .map on observable is not found.
`ERROR in xxx/xxx/dataService.ts(19,14): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`
I looked into the Observable class and I don't see a function called map.

Is there a new way in Angular 6 or `rxjs` to achieve what the tutorial is trying to do?

Here is my .ts file:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    public products = [
        
    ];

    loadProducts() {
        return this.http.get("/api/products")
            .map((data: any[]) => {
                this.products = data;
                return true;
            });
    }
}
```

This is the output from `ng --version`

```
λ ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0 (cli-only)
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.0
@schematics/angular               0.6.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                0.6.0 (cli-only)
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.6.0
```

I did a little digging and in my node_modules/rxjs/observable folder there is no map.* file

```
λ ls -R rxjs\observable
'rxjs\observable':
ArrayLikeObservable.d.ts            IfObservable.d.ts             combineLatest.d.ts       if.js.map
ArrayLikeObservable.js              IfObservable.js               combineLatest.js         interval.d.ts
ArrayLikeObservable.js.map          IfObservable.js.map           combineLatest.js.map     interval.js
ArrayObservable.d.ts                IntervalObservable.d.ts       concat.d.ts              interval.js.map
ArrayObservable.js                  IntervalObservable.js         concat.js                merge.d.ts
ArrayObservable.js.map              IntervalObservable.js.map     concat.js.map            merge.js
BoundCallbackObservable.d.ts        IteratorObservable.d.ts       defer.d.ts               merge.js.map
BoundCallbackObservable.js          IteratorObservable.js         defer.js                 never.d.ts
BoundCallbackObservable.js.map      IteratorObservable.js.map     defer.js.map             never.js
BoundNodeCallbackObservable.d.ts    NeverObservable.d.ts          dom/                     never.js.map
BoundNodeCallbackObservable.js      NeverObservable.js            empty.d.ts               of.d.ts
BoundNodeCallbackObservable.js.map  NeverObservable.js.map        empty.js                 of.js
ConnectableObservable.d.ts          PairsObservable.d.ts          empty.js.map             of.js.map
ConnectableObservable.js            PairsObservable.js            forkJoin.d.ts            onErrorResumeNext.d.ts
ConnectableObservable.js.map        PairsObservable.js.map        forkJoin.js              onErrorResumeNext.js
DeferObservable.d.ts                PromiseObservable.d.ts        forkJoin.js.map          onErrorResumeNext.js.map DeferObservable.js                  PromiseObservable.js          from.d.ts                pairs.d.ts
DeferObservable.js.map              PromiseObservable.js.map      from.js                  pairs.js
EmptyObservable.d.ts                RangeObservable.d.ts          from.js.map              pairs.js.map
EmptyObservable.js                  RangeObservable.js            fromArray.d.ts           race.d.ts
EmptyObservable.js.map              RangeObservable.js.map        fromArray.js             race.js
ErrorObservable.d.ts                ScalarObservable.d.ts         fromArray.js.map         race.js.map
ErrorObservable.js                  ScalarObservable.js           fromEvent.d.ts           range.d.ts
ErrorObservable.js.map              ScalarObservable.js.map       fromEvent.js             range.js
ForkJoinObservable.d.ts             SubscribeOnObservable.d.ts    fromEvent.js.map         range.js.map
ForkJoinObservable.js               SubscribeOnObservable.js      fromEventPattern.d.ts    throw.d.ts
ForkJoinObservable.js.map           SubscribeOnObservable.js.map  fromEventPattern.js      throw.js
FromEventObservable.d.ts            TimerObservable.d.ts          fromEventPattern.js.map  throw.js.map
FromEventObservable.js              TimerObservable.js            fromIterable.d.ts        timer.d.ts
FromEventObservable.js.map          TimerObservable.js.map        fromIterable.js          timer.js
FromEventPatternObservable.d.ts     UsingObservable.d.ts          fromIterable.js.map      timer.js.map
FromEventPatternObservable.js       UsingObservable.js            fromPromise.d.ts         using.d.ts
FromEventPatternObservable.js.map   UsingObservable.js.map        fromPromise.js           using.js
FromObservable.d.ts                 bindCallback.d.ts             fromPromise.js.map       using.js.map
FromObservable.js                   bindCallback.js               generate.d.ts            zip.d.ts
FromObservable.js.map               bindCallback.js.map           generate.js              zip.js
GenerateObservable.d.ts             bindNodeCallback.d.ts         generate.js.map          zip.js.map
GenerateObservable.js               bindNodeCallback.js           if.d.ts
GenerateObservable.js.map           bindNodeCallback.js.map       if.js

'rxjs\observable/dom':
AjaxObservable.d.ts  AjaxObservable.js.map  WebSocketSubject.js      ajax.d.ts  ajax.js.map     webSocket.js
AjaxObservable.js    WebSocketSubject.d.ts  WebSocketSubject.js.map  ajax.js    webSocket.d.ts  webSocket.js.map
```

Comment: This is my first time trying to learn angular and using rxjs and your link helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The link in the comment above needs to be read and bookmarked by anyone migrating to rxjs 6. The information therein is quite valuable!!

Comment: Document is no more available :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In **`rxjs@6`** you can use from as standalone function:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
```

See also migration to rxjs6 guide

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths

**UPDATE**

You need to switch to pipe syntax, make sure you import all operators used from rxjs/operators. For example:

```
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**[DOCUMENTATION](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax)**

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! that link helped a lot. It was actually this section that helped me: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax

I needed to use the pipe syntax.

Comment: @Jonathan I'd suggest to post your own solution, this may help future readers. Self-answers are welcome on SO.

Comment: at Sajeetharan, Sorry your post didn't directly help me. If you edit your post to include the part about piping and show the correct syntax I'll mark it as the answer. @estus I'm going to let Sajeetharan edit his post first then I'll mark his as the correct. Otherwise I'll make my own post if he doesn't do it within some time.

Answer (score 17):

`pipe` is a method on Observable which is used for composing operators

Here is the way how you can use the new method `pipe()` in Version 6:

```
loadProducts() {
    return this.http.get("/api/products").
        pipe(
           map((data: any[]) => {
             this.products = data;
             return true;
           }), catchError( error => {
             return throwError( 'Something went wrong!' )
           });
        )
}
```

Keep in mind that with Version 6 you should now use `catchError` and `throwError` instead of: `catch` and `throw`. Here is the correct import with Version 6:

`import { Observable, of, throwError, ...} from "rxjs"`

`import { map, catchError, ...} from "rxjs/operators"`

Answer (score 7):

You have to change to pipe syntax:

```
import { Http  } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {map, catchError} from "rxjs/operators";

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

list():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .pipe(
      map((e:Response)=> e.json()),
      catchError((e:Response)=> throwError(e))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the way to import map e.g.

`import { map } from "rxjs/operators";`

then use pipe with map. see the example for better understanding

```
import {Http,Headers,Response} from '@angular/http';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactServiceService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getContactList(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/contact')
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Angular new version actually does not support .map. A few changes have been done in the new angular version. You can check on these by visiting the angular website, but here is a solution of these problems; run these commands in
cmd destination of your project:

```
 npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

and enjoy with old technique, but don't forget to add these lines in shared service:

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Answer (score 0):

For some obscure reason `rxjs-compat` sometimes doesn't get picked up automatically, you can import it yourself, in `polyfills.ts` for example:

`import 'rxjs-compat';`

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 6x with rxjs 6.3.3 you can do this. In the file(app.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {    

  _url = 'http://...';
  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }
  articles: Observable<any>;

  // Method to get info
  getAPIRest() {       
    const params = new HttpParams().set('parameter', 'value');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Autorization', 'auth-token');
    this.articles = this.http.get(this._url + '/articles', { params, headers })
             .pipe( retry(3),
                    map((data => data),
                    catchError(err => throwError(err))));
  }
```

}